# Chrome Extension - Migration to Manifest v3 - chrome.permissions user gesture issue

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, permissions, migration, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have built a chrome extension in manifest version 2 and am now looking at migrating to version 3. As part of this migration I have come across an issue when trying to toggle an optional permission to use the chrome notifications api.

Since you can't request a new permission from a content script as the api is not accessible from a content script, you have to send a message to the background script to perform the request and return the response to the content script. This worked as expected with version 2, now I am receiving this error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: This function must be called during a user gesture

This means that the extension wants the permission request to be initiated on the back of an event initiated by a user action, such as a click. This indicates that the extension wishes the permission request to be completed from the content script but as stated above this is impossible.

Could anyone illuminate me if I'm missing something?

Content Script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  {message: 'requestPermissions', permissions: ['notifications']},
  (res) => console.log(res)
);
```

Background Script:

```
export function requestPermissions(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  const {permissions} = request;

  new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.permissions.request(
      {
        permissions
      },
      (granted) => resolve(granted)      
    );
  }).then((res) => sendResponse(res));

  return true;
}
```

Comment: It should work because the "user activation" flag should be internally sent along with the message so apparently it's yet another bug in MV3, which is not surprising because despite its forceful promotion by Google, MV3 is still beta quality.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I assumed this must be a Google MV3 issue

Comment: Was this ever resolved @TomIsherwood

Comment: In 116 you can certainly call `chrome.permissions` from a content script. I'm assuming that scripts run from a script tag in the popup are actually "content Scripts", which appears to be the case. [The docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) appear to be completely wrong.